# Can't override textAllCaps for buttons on style under android 21

Tags: android, layout, android-5.0-lollipop

This is how I set my buttons.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_login"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/button_login" />
```

This is my style on values folder.

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="ButtonStyleBase" />

<style name="ButtonStyleBase">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/padding</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_regular</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_clickable</item>
</style>
```

And this is my style on values-v21 folder

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="ButtonStyleBase">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

But the text is always uppercase on buttons. If I set it directly on the button it will get back to normal, though. I changed the color to see if the style for api 21 was being used and it was, the button text color changed to black on api 21. I know the default theme sets textAllCaps as true for buttons because google thought it would be super-duper-cool, but shouldn't it prioritize my style?

Edit: neverming, I forgot to write "android:" on the style.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue and this is what worked for me:

```
<style name="Theme.CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In **styles.xml**

Include the button style in your AppTheme(Which will be using in **Application** or **Activity**)

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>    
</style>
```

create button style

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

If you found any issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the following line does not say "android:" before "textAllCaps"

`<item name="textAllCaps" tools:targetApi="ice_cream_sandwich">false</item>`

Answer (score 0):

Your style on values-v21 folder its correct

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="ButtonStyleBase">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

but same time Api level above 21 your style paste on values-v19 and also style folder xml