# Why text in button Register and Login so large?

Tags: android, xml

This is my XML file. All text in button is large.
I used `android:textAllCaps="false"`, but no result.In what may be a problem?

All literals are declared in the strings.xml.
Nowhere isn't even talk of the big letters. I think problem in invested LinearLayout.

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_color"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_start" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feeld_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/login"
            android:phoneNumber="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/feeld_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_register"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/register"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_login"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<resources>
<string name="app_name">Lesson 6. Registration Form</string>
<string name="register">Register</string>
<string name="login">Login</string>
<string name="password">Password</string>
```

```
package com.egoriku.lesson6registrationform;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String login = "egorikftp";
    private final String password = "androidN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ImageView mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final EditText loginText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feeld_login);
        final EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feeld_password);
        Button buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        Button buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (loginText.getText().length() == 0) {
                    loginText.setError("Введите логин");
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_error);
                }

                if (passwordText.getText().length() == 0) {
                    passwordText.setError("Введите пароль");
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_error);
                } else if (loginText.getText().toString().equals(login) && passwordText.getText().toString().equals(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы успешно вошли в систему!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loginText.setText(null);
                    passwordText.setText(null);
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_ok);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Логин/Пароль введен неверно!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_error);
                    loginText.setText(null);
                    passwordText.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (loginText.getText().length() == 0) {
                    loginText.setError("Введите логин");
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_error);
                }

                if (passwordText.getText().length() == 0) {
                    passwordText.setError("Введите пароль");
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_error);
                } else {
                    //login = loginText.getText().toString();
                    //password = passwordText.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loginText.setText(null);
                    passwordText.setText(null);
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_ok);
                }
            }

        });


    }
}
```

Screen of my program. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: where's second layout and java class? :-)

Comment: Post your strings.xml file and your java class in which you use these buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to simply add this line inside your **Button tag in xml**

```
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

Adding this line will show the text of your Button as you want whether capital or small depending upon the text in

```
android:text=" .... "
```

and change text size which fits perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`Button`'s widget in Android uses this `style` by default:

```
<item name="textAppearanceButton">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.Button</item>
```

Which enable by default the `textAllCaps` to true. As you can see in [values/styles_base_text.xml](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/febed84a3a3cb7c2cb80d580d79c31e22e9643a5/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base_text.xml) of AppCompat theme, it could refer to the same style:

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_button_material</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Therefore, you need to override the current theme by your own. This question has been already resolved with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27230326/2668136) provided by @Galya. The steps are:

- Create a new style for `android:textAppearanceButton`
- Use the style's parent from the Base theme: `@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button`
- Then, set caps to false with `textAllCaps`.

However, this will change all text caps buttons in the project. If you only need to handle these two buttons, I'd suggest you to create two `TextView`s and provide an `onClickListener` on them.